# Correct way for Adding image from an imageView to return an HTML string

Tags: iphone, html, ios, objective-c

I am taking a printout of a view which I customised to print some text and an image from an imageView.

The following code works but instead of the image a blank box appears.

```
 -(NSString *)prepareHTMLText {

    NSMutableString *body = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>"];


        [body appendString:@"<h2>Ingredients</h2>"];
        [body appendFormat:@"<p>%@ %@</p>", @"text", @"TEStText"];

        [body appendFormat:@"<img src=\"%@\"/>", myImageView.image];

    [body appendString:@"</body></html>"];
    return body;
}
```

Comment: You have to set the path for that image. In this way you are passing the reference of that image so it is not showing the image it is just a memory address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[download Base64.h and .m files from here](http://www.imthi.com/blog/programming/iphone-sdk-base64-encode-decode.php)  drag them into your project.import Base64.h in your .h file and try the below code it works

```
-(NSString *)prepareHTMLText {
    NSString *str1 = [Base64 encode:UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImageView.image)];
    NSMutableString *body = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>"];
    [body appendString:@"<h2>Ingredients</h2>"];
    [body appendFormat:@"<p>%@ %@</p>", @"text", @"TEStText"];
    [body appendFormat:@"<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,%@\" alt=\"\" height=\"100\" width=\"100\"/>",str1];
    [body appendString:@"</body></html>"];
    return body;
}
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly assign image like this to your body.You need to do follwing

1. Convert `myImageView.image` to `NSData`
2. Store the contents of `NSData` in document  directory with a unique name.
3. Pass the path of image stored in document directory to the body.

Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

```
[body appendFormat:@"<img src=\"%@\"/>", myImageView.image];
```

You want to append the path of this image, but here you just appended a description of image. (By default it contains something like image class and size..). It seems that the output string will be sent to a webview (or a browser?). The webview can not recognize and find the image with . You need to specify a correct path for the webview to find the image.

Comment: How could i get the path @onevcat. i am taking the images from the photo library of the device.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have the image in the bundle, so get the file path for the image and use that path instead of myImageView.image. Hope this will help you.